# JSON'd localStorage array of GMap markers get parsed as non-markers

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

I've already asked numerous questions concerning the project I'm working on now and have hit yet another wall. I'm storing an array of Google Map markers in localStorage as a means to store searched history from the user. When I pull the data back out of localStorage via parse and retrocycle it, it appears they are no longer "Marker" objects anymore. Despite this, I still see most of the values that I should (i.e. a latitude and a longitude (only they aren't really named that)).

Here is my code:

```
var markers = [];
var cache = localStorage.getItem("searchHistory");
testCache = JSON.retrocycle(JSON.parse(cache));
for(i = 0; i < testCache.length; i++)
{
    newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        title: //what to do here?
        position: //what to do here?
    });
    markers.push(newMarker);
}
//On places_changed create new marker for location
addListenerToMarker(map,marker);
if(!markerExistsInMarkers(marker,markers))
{
    markers.push(marker);
    localStorage.setItem("searchHistory",JSON.stringify(JSON.decycle(markers)));
}
```

I've tried several things like:

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng(testCache[i][1],testCache[i][2])
```

Which supposedly worked for someone but it's showing up as NaN for me.

And:

```
position: testCache[i].position
```

Doesn't work because it's not a marker object anymore. How can I access the fields in testCache in such a way that they return what I want them to?

Comment: what does `cache` array look like? How was it created?

Comment: Looks like, for the most part, a massive array of garbled text. It's created via the localStorage.setItem line at the bottom of my initial code block.

Comment: you need to save the original data that created the markers and pass to marker constructor as you would if the marker had never existed before

Comment: So NOT save marker objects but save the information I would have used to build one?

Comment: yes, exactly. Google adds a ton of other properties and caches the data also. No way to replicate that other than start as if it never existed

Comment: if the data is being changed within the map...like markers being moved...you would likely need to bind the event callbacks back to your storage and update accordingly. There may also be API methods to extract all data...I've just never had to do that

Comment: Well, your suggestion of just copying relevant information into localStorage as opposed to the marker objects themselves is working like a charm. Thanks!